# How to unit test function called in service's constructor?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, service, jasmine, karma-runner

How can I test, in the service's spec file, that a function is called in the constructor? For example:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class myService {
  

    constructor() {
       this.myFunction();
    }

    myFunction(){}
}
```

So how can I test that my function was called?

```
beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.get(myService);
```

I can't spy on the service before the testbed.get, and I tried:

```js
it('should demonstrate myFunction called in constructor', () => {
  const spy = spyOn (myService, 'myFunction');
  const serv = new myService();

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But this is failing to say spy wasn't called!

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering, the method you want to spy on is defined inside the service you are trying to test? If that's the case you should rather stub any calls inside your function. It is usually not a good idea to stub methods inside the thing you want to test and in this particular case it's not just a bad idea but will most likely not work.

Comment: thank you for the help, howevernot sure what you mean, but I got it working with the help of slideshowp2,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [spyOn(obj, methodName) → {Spy}](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOn) to spy the `myFunction` on `MyService.prototype`.

E.g.

`service.ts`:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  constructor() {
    this.myFunction();
  }

  myFunction() {}
}
```

`service.test.ts`:

```js
import { MyService } from './service';

describe('63819030', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const myFunctionSpy = spyOn(MyService.prototype, 'myFunction').and.stub();
    const service = new MyService();
    expect(myFunctionSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks a million, in my situation it didn't need the and.stub(), the key was the prototype, also, I discovered you need to spy on all other methods in the constructor(), at least in my actual situation

Comment: It does not work Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203